# In Java (android), what is a good way to create accurate consecutive timers?

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown

What would be the most accurate solution to have multiple consecutive timers in Java / android? Or in other words, what is the best option to delay the next piece of code until the current timer has finished?

Background information if the question is unclear:
To practice coding, I would like to create a free app w/o ads to help practice freediving. The basic idea is to have several timers that run after each other. Example:

1. 2 minutes breath up
2. hold your breath for 2 minutes
3. 2 minutes breath up
4. hold your breath for 2 minutes + 15 seconds
5. 2 minutes breath up
6. hold your breath for 2 minutes + 15 seconds + 15 seconds
   and so on; usually 8 rounds of breath holding which leads to 16 consecutive timers

At first I thought I can use the timer class but I don't know how to pause the code until the timer is finished. So all the timers ran simultaneously. 
I have read about CountDownLatch and Handler but I don't have enough experience to judge what would be best for my purpose. I did a python version before and used sleep. It worked fine, but for longer timers it was inaccurate by a few seconds which is a problem.

Another option, I believe, is to use a regular timer but run a while loop until the displayed text == 0. I don't know if this infinite loop would crash the application, interfere with the timer's accuracy or has any other negative side effects.

Any help / thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many times. Search for Timer, Executor, ScheduledExecutorService, and real-time Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check System time every few milliseconds.
You can achieve the same effect via `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `Handler`.

1. save the System time at the beginning of timer.
2. Set Handler to run every 100 ms(0.1 second) and check the current System time.
3. If (current time - beginning time) > 2000, proceed next step.

Something like below...

```
class TimerHandler extends Handler
{
    private long start;
    private long timeGap;

    public void set(long gap)
    {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.timeGap = gap;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(curr - start > timeGap)
        {
            // do what you want.
            // If you want your timer to keep on running,
            // reset start.
        }

        // send Next Message after 100 ms.
        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(-1, 100);
    }
}
```

In your Activity or something:

```
public void startTimer(long gap)
{
    TimerHandler handler = new TimerHandler();
    handler.set(gap);
    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(-1, 100);
}

startTimer(2000);
```

Note that you can reduce error by using small nextTimer when calling `sendEmptyMessageDelayed()`, but it will cause your OS to check your Thread more frequently, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you Suhyeon. That idea seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm still having a few troubles on figuring out how to correctly start the next action but I think I have the direction now :)
(I believe I have to start the next action directly from the handleMessage method right? If I add it in the startTimer method, it will start immediately and ignore the delay)